# PowerShell - How to Concatenate variable with text? on same line on text file

Tags: powershell

I'm having difficulties to join a text with 1 string how do I make this join without breaking line in power shell? can you help me.

**I Want This:**

```
> PlaybackDevice=AudioDevice 
> RingerDevice=AudioDevice
> RecordDevice=AudioDeviceRecord
```

**But i have this on execute:**

```
     PlaybackDevice= 
$audio.Name
     RingerDevice=  
$audio.Name 
     RecordDevice= 
$mic.Name
```

**This is my code:**

```
Add-Content "C:\burn.txt*" "RingerDevice=" $audio.Name 
Add-Content"C:\burn.txt*" "RecordDevice=" $mic.Name 
Add-Content "C:\burn.txt*" "PlaybackDevice=" $audio.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Add-Content "C:\burn.txt*" "RingerDevice=$($audio.Name)"
Add-Content "C:\burn.txt*" "RecordDevice=$($mic.Name)"
Add-Content "C:\burn.txt*" "PlaybackDevice=$($audio.Name)"
```

Comment: I can't be the only one that almost always resorts to something like  ("PlaybackDevice=" + $audio.Name) in these situations simply bc the appearance of the string interpolation expression syntax is so jarring, hah. esp. for very short expressions

Comment: @diopside I've been there too!

Comment: You cannot have a "*" in a path.

Comment: Amazing! very thanks for this for helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

"*" is not allowed in the a hard drive path. You must put ALL of content you want to write in "" or ''.  Given that you have a variable such as "$audio.Name" it is treated as a object that has a label called "name" and a value called "logictech" in my example below.  Add-Content only wants the value by using $() you can expand the variable and only give the value. e.g. $($audio.Name). Never write to the C:\ path. It is block in many places for security reasons. Run the code below for a working example.

```
$audio = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name     = "logictech"
}

$mic= [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name     = "MyMic"
}

Add-Content -path "$env:temp\burn.txt" -Value "RingerDevice=$($audio.Name)"
Add-Content -Path "$env:temp\burn.txt" -Value  "RecordDevice=$($mic.Name)"
Add-Content -Path "$env:temp\burn.txt" "PlaybackDevice=$($audio.Name)"

sleep 10

Start-Process "$env:temp\burn.txt"
```